# Инструменты SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, инструменты-разработчика

Подскажите название программ для взаимодействия с SQL серверами, сейчас мне нужна программа для работы с Oracle DB 10g XE. Штатных средств не хватает к сожалению..

Нашел [EMS SQL Management Studio](http://www.sqlmanager.net/), но она к сожалению платная...

Comment: А чем SQL Developer не устраивает то?

Comment: Впервые слышу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Настоящая классика жанра: [SQL Navigator](http://www.quest.com/sql-navigator/), [Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-oracle/). Разумеется, они платные.

Бесплатное классическое решение: [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html). В действительности, его почти всегда хватает, если не требуется серьёзная разработка большого продукта.

Answer (score 1):

Есть OraDeveloper Studio ([Инструментарий для разработки и администрирования Oracle баз](http://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/oracle/)) (русская версия бесплатная)
Конкретно про эту сказать ничего не могу, но их решения для MS SQL Server выручали пару раз.

Comment: Остановился на OraDeveloper Studio, всё вроде хорошо, но немного интерфейс страдает.

Answer (score 1):

[TOra](http://torasql.com/about).

> TOra is an open-source multi-platform database management GUI.

Comment: Не смог подключиться к Oracle 10g XE =(

Comment: http://torasql.com/Download

....
Important! Because of legal reasons TOra comes with a stub oci.dll file which makes it possible to use TOra with non Oracle databases even when Oracle client is not installed. If you need to access Oracle - you must install Oracle client (for example oracle instant client) and delete stub oci.dll from TOra installation folder. 
....

Answer (score 0):

Не понимаю, зачем нужны сторонние средства, когда нативный [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) предлагает более чем широкие возможности. Устанавливается вместе с самим сервером (в Enterprise версии точно).

Comment: В Express Edition идет только sqlPlus и веб-клиент...

Comment: Можно бесплатно скачать с оффициального сайта, предварительно зарегистрировавшись.